# How to prevent CKEdictor to replace brackets

Tags: ckeditor4.x

When I use setData method of CKEditor 4.x, it replaces brackets and text between them with an empty string. For example the below string:

> Hello, {name} {family}, Welcome to ...

is replaced with

> Hello, , Welcome to ...

How can I prevent this?